# Lectura de un archivo PDF que cambia de nombre constantemente

Tags: python

Tengo un pequeño script en python donde manipulo un archivo `.pdf`.
Mi problema es que el nombre de este archivo cambia de forma constante y debo cambiar el nombre manualmente; ¿no existe alguna libreria o forma en la que pueda leer cualquier archivo .pdf sin importar el nombre que tenga?

Este es el código que estoy usando, donde se puede ver que al final de la primera ruta está el nombre del pdf que debe cambiar según necesidades.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import os
import zipfile

inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open("/Users/Usuario/Documents/pdfPru/pdfcertinorm.pdf", "rb"))

for i in range(inputpdf.numPages):
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i))
    with open("/xampp/htdocs/firma/pdfNuevos/document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)




pdf_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/xampp/htdocs/firma/pdfNuevos/archivos.zip', 'w')

for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('/xampp/htdocs/firma/pdfNuevos'):

    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdf_zip.write(os.path.join('/xampp/htdocs/firma/pdfNuevos', file), file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

pdf_zip.close()
```

Comment: el pdf que cambia es `pdfcertinorm`??

Comment: si exactamente ese es

Comment: ¿Puedes tener más de un archivo en esta carpeta? ¿Que esperas cuando esto ocurra? ¿Procesar uno o procesar todos?

Comment: ¿Qué significa que cambia de nombre constantemente? ¿Que la próxima vez que ejecutes tu script el fichero pdf a procesar a lo mejor es otro? ¿Qué tienen en común? ¿Siempre la misma carpeta? ¿Es el único pdf en esa carpeta? En este caso te basta con obtener la lista de pdfs de la carpeta y quedarte con el primer elemento. Si hay varios ¿cómo sabes cuál te interesa? A lo mejor necesitas mirar la fecha de creación de cada pdf y quedarte con el más reciente.

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que yo lo haría es separar la ruta de la carpeta del archivo

```
CARPETA = '/Users/Usuario/Documents/pdfPru/'
listafiles = os.listdir(CARPETA)
listafiles = [x.upper() for x in listafiles if x.upper().endswith('.PDF')]
```

Lo que hago acá con `os.listdir()` es crear una lista con todos los archivos contenidos en la carpeta. Luego lo paso todo a mayúsculas para no tener errores si el archivo termina en .pdf o .PDF o .pDf, etc. Y si ves el `if`, solo incluyo los archivos que terminen en `.pdf`

Con eso ya para invocar al archivo harías:

```
if len(listafiles) == 1:
    inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(CARPETA,listafiles[0]),'rb'))
```

El `if` es opcional, solo crea el inputPDF si hay un solo archivo .pdf. Si quieres abrir varios, podrías abrirlos dentro de un `for archivo in listafiles:`